# Class with dynamic this.variables

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm creating a class where I would be able to have in my constructor dynamic variables, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way or if it is valid.

Example static:
My class:

```
class MyClass{
constructor(options){
    this.propertyname = options.value;
    this.propertyname = options.value;
    this.propertyname = options.value;

}
}
```

Does this example would be the same of the above? My only issue would be that the example I have wasn't making the options value assign to "this".
My class:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(options){
        for (var property in options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                this[property] = options[property];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Calling:

```
var example = new MyClass({
    property1:          "Something",
    property2:          "NY" ,
    });
```

Comment: Should work just fine, what's the problem ?

Comment: @adeneo one of the problems is that giving me in the end a undefined value.

Comment: Works for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/czdrg2j3/

Comment: @adeneo cant understand why in google chrome is appearing me, for example not using in jsfiddle, but in a html page locally.

Comment: Well, something is obviously different, you have to figure out what, I can't really help you there !

Answer (score 0):

Either assigning object properties using regular assignment syntax or using a loop produces the same result.

BTW, I would use `Object.keys` instead of `for..in` in order to get own object's properties only:

```js
var obj = {};
var options = {
  property1: "hello",
  property2: "world"
};

// Change "obj" with "this" and it'll produce the same result when
// being in class' constructor scope
Object.keys(options).forEach(propertyName => obj[propertyName] = options[propertyName]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```